# After hiding bottomsheet, how to drag it back up?

Tags: android

After dragging-down a bottomsheet, and it hides itself off the screen (because of app:behavior_hideable="true"), how do you get it back?

Drag-up doesn't work. I have to leave the activity and come back to get the bottomsheet back.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:text="Bottom Sheet"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I would be really interested since I am faced with the same problem currently

Answer (score 0):

Use the bottomsheet callback to detect the state change.

```
BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior;
    protected BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    };


 mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
```

Use show() to display the bottom sheet

```
 private void showBottomSheet(){
        if(!bottomSheet.isVisible()){
        bottomsheet.show(((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomsheet.getTag());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This serves to instantly slide the bottomsheet back up to its max height. I'm interested in hiding it, then at some point in time, dragging back up to show it (up to peek height).

Comment: @MarsAndBack, are you using BottomSheetDialog,BottomSheetDialogFragment or within your layout?

Comment: Use this code to show again
bottomSheet.show(((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomsheet.getTag());

Comment: @MarsAndBack Did you ever manage to solve this? I would be really interested since I am faced with the same problem currently